# Обновление данных графика на OxyPlot в Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, graphics, oxyplot

Используется для рисования графика на `Xamarin Oxyplot.Forms`. График рисуется верно и обновление контента происходит. Однако, не могу начисто обновить контент. Метод `InvalidatePlot(true)` отлично обновляет интерфейс, если добавлены новые точки, но как мне сбросить построенные `Axies`?

Удаляю все точки из модели, добавляют новые, вызываю `InvalidatePlot(true)`, новые точки добавляются, но `Axies` остается предыдущий.

Answer (score 1):

Для обновления начисто перебейте сорц самого графика. Т.е. не точки конкретные, а всю модель.

Comment: При повторном заходе на странице заново создаю модель и plotview, но новый plotview со старыми axies создается

Comment: Если память не обманывает, там есть свойство Plot, содержащее обе оси, плюс собственно точки графика. Вот именно этот Plot вам и надо перебить, в случае с WPF - уведомить об этом форму. В WinForm как оно делается - без понятия.

Comment: вот мой вопрос на гите у них. Код прозрачный. https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/676

Comment: >Then i should reset all plotview, clear chart and start new graphic. I do this
Вместо этого просто заново создавайте plotview.

Comment: да, на сколько я понимаю, то создание нового контрола не должно сохранять параметры старого. Как мне поступить?

Comment: Я почему так и пишу - такое поведение почти у всех графических либ, проще создать элемент заново, чем почистить его содержимое и заполнить.

Comment: Пытаюсь обновить вот так:modPlotView.Model = null; modPlotView.Model = new PlotModel();

Comment: Аналогично. И у меня так оси перерисовываются.

Comment: да, но в моем случае, такой код modPlotView.Model = null; modPlotView.Model = new PlotModel(); оси не перерисовываются(

Comment: Без понятия как взаимодействие с формой организовано в WinForm, нужно её оповестить в обоих случаях.